# VBA code for moving completed rows to another sheet causes strange behavior

Tags: excel, vba

Disclaimer: I am not well-versed in VBA and have pieced together the following code by reading various blogs, etc.

My code "works" in that it moves rows whose status is changed to Done from the Active sheet to the Completed sheet. This was the point of the code.

The issue comes when I use the drag button (the little black corner thingy) to create another row on the source sheet (Active sheet). It for some reason copies the header row from the Active sheet to a new row on the Completed sheet.

It must be due to the copy and paste action, but I'm not sure how it's tied to dragging the table to create a row (if at all). Any help or guidance to this VBA amateur would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'If Cell that is edited is in column H and the value is Done
    If Target.Column = 8 And Target.Value = "Done" Then
        'Define last row on completed worksheet to know where to place the row of data
        LrowCompleted = Sheets("Completed").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        'Copy and paste data
        Range("B" & Target.Row & ":K" & Target.Row).Copy Sheets("Completed").Range("B" & LrowCompleted + 1)
        'Delete Row from Project List
        Range("B" & Target.Row & ":K" & Target.Row).Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` hides potential errors. Best to implement true error handling. There will be an error for example if `Target` is a multi-cell range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`On Error Resume Next` hides potential errors. For example, `Target.Value = "Done"` will throw an error if `Target` is a multi-cell range.

Perhaps try the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column <> 8 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Value = "Done" Then
        Dim LrowCompleted as Long
        LrowCompleted = Sheets("Completed").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        Me.Range("B" & Target.Row & ":K" & Target.Row).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Completed").Range("B" & LrowCompleted + 1)

        Me.Range("B" & Target.Row & ":K" & Target.Row).Delete xlShiftUp
    End If

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```